# what's the difference between class type variables or instantiating in a constructor/method

Tags: java, design-patterns, netbeans, composition

```
public class MotoXCellPhone {

    //assume there's a speaker class
    private BlueToothSpeaker speaker; 

    //why instantiate in constructor?

    MotoXCellPhone() {
        speaker = new BlueToothSpeaker();
    }

    //or if i instantiate in a method?
    public BlueToothSpeaker useSpeaker() {
        speaker = new BlueToothSpeaker();
        return speaker;
    }
}
```

why would i want to instantiate a class in another class' constructor? i don't fully understand composition yet so i'm fuzzy on the 'why" of everything

Comment: Please remember to mark you question as "answered", if it was answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you instantiate it in the method, you'll create a new one each time that method is called.  If that doesn't make sense -- if you want one `BlueToothSpeaker` object to be tied to the `MotoXCellPhone` object for its lifetime -- then you need to create it (or inject it) in the constructor.

Comment: THANKS! it's more clear to me. says i wanted to connect the phone to the speaker (assume proper methods/variables were in both classes) would i use put a class reference as an instance variable?

Comment: If you wanted the speaker to be a property of the phone, you'd have a field of type `BlueToothSpeaker` in which you stored the speaker.

Comment: would that logic still apply even if the speaker was an independent object, and the phone class just "used" that speaker object?

Comment: In that case you might want to pass in the speaker to the constructor instead of instantiate a new one.

Comment: @Bryan where would the speaker come from? Some call has to create the speaker. The technique Louis Wasserman has mentioned is also know as [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (not coming from this context, but still applicable here)

Comment: the speaker is a separate class. in that case i'd pass it from the main()

Answer (score 1):

The argument is as follows: if someone else uses your code, they might not call `useSpeakser()` and thus `speakers` might be `null`. Instantiating `speakers` within the constructor asserts that it will not be `null`.

Comment: okay so i should set a class reference instance variable, and the instantiate it in the constructor if my MotoX class were to use the speaker?

Comment: Depends on your application. Normally, it is easier to assume that attributes are not `null`. For convenience you can call `useSpeaker()` in the constructor, avoiding code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor will run and instantiate BlueToothSpeaker right when MotoXCell is instantiated, whereas the method will only instantiate the new class when it is called.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of member initialization, each with pros and cons, I'll try to enumerate them:

1. **early-initialization**:

   - done when declaring the member, or within the class constructor
   - pros:

     - the created object begins it's lifecycle at the same time as it's "parent", and is available at any time without needing to do any checks
     - in the case of a worker class, the created object can start working right away
   - cons:

     - more CPU/memory used for that object
     - depending on the context the object might never be used
2. **lazy-initialization**:

   - done on demand, usually within its getter
   - pros:

     - the object will be created only when firstly needed, thus reduces its CPU/memory usage
     - no context dependent, if the member is not needed at all, it will not be created
   - cons:

     - you will need to always access the member via it's getter within the "parent" class, otherwise you might run into crashes
     - care must be taken when dealing with multithreading (e.g. a lock must be used), and this has a performance impact

Depending of the implementation of your class you might choose one over another.